# WPF Datagrid make cell readonly based on another cell in a same row with binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have very simple WPF datagrid with two columns one with checkbox and another with string type.
I need to make GridTextColumn readonly when GridCheckBoxColumn is checked or vice versa.
But I want to achieve this with binding and MVVM pattern.

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid AllowFiltering="True"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Decades}"
                       ColumnSizer="Star"
                       GridValidationMode="InView"
                       AllowEditing="True">
            <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="{x:Static properties:Strings.Id}" MappingName="Id" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="{x:Static properties:Strings.Name}" MappingName="Name" UpdateTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="{x:Static properties:Strings.StartDate}" MappingName="StartDate"/>
                <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="{x:Static properties:Strings.EndDate}" MappingName="EndDate"/>
                <syncfusion:GridCheckBoxColumn HeaderText="{x:Static properties:Strings.NonStandard}" MappingName="NonStandard"/>
                <syncfusion:GridTextColumn HeaderText="{x:Static properties:Strings.PayDay}" MappingName="PayDay" AllowEditing="{Binding ????}"}"/>
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done in a simple way.
One solution - is to use the DataGridTemplateColumn in the cell template of which the TextBox is located.
And the TextBox is set to bind the IsReadOnly property in the way you need.